# SQL Server OPENJSON returning last element as null

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm trying to use OPENJSON to return values from an array of JSON objects, but the last requested element is always coming up NULL.

The basic object is:

```
DECLARE
@response NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[
                                {   
                                    "uniqueID":"T0139"
                                ,   "title":"Item 1"
                                },
                                {   
                                    "uniqueID":"J0295"
                                ,   "title":"Item 3"
                                }
                            ]'
```

SELECT ISJON(@response) returns true.

If I run:

```
SELECT
    uniqueID
,   title
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@response) WITH (
                        uniqueID    NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.uniqueID' 
                    ,   title       NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.title' 
                    AS JSON)
```

I get back:

```
uniqueID    title
T0139       NULL
J0295       NULL
```

However, if I throw a bogus column on the back of my statement:

```
SELECT
    uniqueID
,   title
,   doesntExist
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@response) WITH (
                        uniqueID    NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.uniqueID' 
                    ,   title       NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.title' 
                    ,   doesntExist NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.doesntExist' 
                    AS JSON)
```

Now I get back a value for title:

```
uniqueID    title   doesntExist
T0139       Item 1  NULL
J0295       Item 3  NULL
```

The data is clearly there, and returnable. So why is it that this only works when I request a missing node? What's wrong with my first statement?

DB Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa985e8007dedbc5dea9b6b7e4243826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have one parenthesis out of place.  Check out the last line.

```
SELECT
    uniqueID
,   title
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@response) WITH (
                        uniqueID    NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.uniqueID' 
                    ,   title       NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.title' 
                    ) AS JSON
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I swear that I copied this from somewhere that worked, I must be slowly going blind.

Comment: I've been there.. I think one misplaced paren has been the downfall of us all at one time or another.  :)

Comment: I think that I intentionally used it inside the parens elsewhere in order to force some formatting on a result, and thus didn't realize that I picked a bad example to copy.